# Spring form input value get lost when manually add FieldError into bindingResult

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have a web controller in Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute Device device, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    return getDefaultView();
}
```

jsp view:

```
<form:form role="form" commandName="device">
    <form:input path="name" class="form-control"/>
    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="text-danger"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Suppose that my Device class has only one attribute **name**. I want to validate it (example length >= 5)

```
public class DeviceDTO {
    @Size(min = 5)
    String name;
    //getter & setter..
}
```

After run this, I input string "abc" in **name** field then submit, The form will show as:
[image]

We can see there are old value & error message. But in some cases that I want to manually validate with my own criteria (that annotation cannot handle), I remove @Size annotation and change my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute Device device, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if(device.getName().length() < 6)
        bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("device", "name", "custom error"));
    return getDefaultView();
}
```

But now, when I submit form with "abc" value, my custom error is shown but my old value of **name** field not
[image]

But if I use directly ${device.name}, it still shows "abc" value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute Device device, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if(device.getName().length() < 6)
        bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("device", "name",device.getName(), false, null, null, "custom error"));
    return getDefaultView();
}
```